# Trouble deleting a tr with ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to delete a table row, my button works and my product deletes from the database, however it doesn't delete on the page until a refresh and I always get "It Failed" even tho it worked... What am I doing so wrong? seems like the "success" isn't being called.

```
$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var token = $(this).data("token");
   $.ajax(
           {
               url: "/eventlineitem/"+id,
               type: 'DELETE',
               dataType: "JSON",
               data: {
                   "id": id,
                   "_method": 'DELETE',
                   "_token": token
               },
               success: function ()
               {
                   console.log("it Work");
               }
           });

   console.log("It failed");
 });
```

Here is my html

```
<tr class="item{{$item->id}}">
  <td class="align-center" scope="row">{{$item->product->id}}</td>
  <td class="align-center">{{$item->quantity}}</td>
  <td><a href="/products/{{$item->product->id}}">{{$item->product->name}}</a></td>
  <td class="align-center">{{$item->warehouse_id}}</td>
  <td class="align-center">{{$item->product->location}}</td>
  <td><div class="switch">
  <label><input type="checkbox"><span class="lever switch-col-green"></span></label>
  </div></td>
  <td><i class="material-icons deleteProduct" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">delete</i></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `type: 'DELETE'` is valid?

Comment: Yeah I guess lol when I press my <i> the row deletes from the database

Comment: Learn something new I guess, https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7

Comment: I just read that, what exactly am I supposed to be learning?? I get a status OK/200 and it DOES delete from the database

Comment: Sorry, was merely meant for people like myself who weren't aware of that type. See my answer below.

Comment: Oh okay perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: maybe it is but thats A LOT of info to take in for a newcomer...

Comment: `console.log("It failed");` will always be executed on delete click as per the current code. So even if it works, it will display it failed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you expected the html to know you deleted the row?

I think you should create a variable before the Ajax call

```
var target = $(this).parents("tr");
```

And then in the ajax.success call

```
target.remove()
```

Comment: I think target is <i> here. Though we can do target.parents('tr').remove()

Comment: I tried this, still the same issue as before. it gets deleted from the database I get a status "OK" / 200

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function like this

```
success: function ()
               {
                   $(".item"+id).remove();
                   console.log("it Work");
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    console.log("it Work");
}
```

By the way, if console.log is being fired here then you know success worked.

Comment: I still get "it failed", still deletes from database and when the page is refreshed, the row is gone.

Comment: Is the console logging anything? Have you confirmed success is being fired?

Comment: console logs "it failed" and the status i get back is OK/200 (useing laravel devtools)

Comment: It will always say fail because you have it outside of the ajax call. Are you getting back the 'it worked' one?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're returning any data because you're running `type:delete` and my guess is success will only fire if it has received something. If you're confident it's going to work every time then you could just remove the row outside the ajax, otherwise I think you need to return something in order for it to fire the success.

Comment: I think laravel is returning a status but i did however add a flash message. I know you might not understand, but what im getting at is that laravel does return something even when i force something. I'll add the laravel tag to see if anyone finds an error with laravel.

Comment: Try `dataType: "html"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code:

```
$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
    var _selector = $(this);
    var id = _selector.data("id");
    var token = _selector.data("token");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/eventlineitem/"+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token
        },
        success: function (){
            console.log("it Work");
            _selector.parents('tr.item' + id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if its work for you.

Comment: No this code does not work, YES my product deletes from the database but does not remove it from the dom. I got it to work with manually returing a message from laravel instead of using status code then using your remove